# How to select starting value for covariates in NLME

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions, nlme

```
library(nlme)
Loblolly$age2 <- as.factor(ifelse(Loblolly$age < 12.5, 0, 1))
```

Here I define a binary covariate that I'm interested in.

```
model <- nlme(height ~ (R0) + 1,
               data = Loblolly,
               fixed = list(R0 ~ 1 + (age2)),
               random = list(Seed = pdDiag(list(R0 ~ 1))),
               start = list(fixed = c(R0 = -8.5, age2 = 1)))
```

Running this gives me the error,

```
Error in nlme.formula(height ~ (R0) + 1, data = Loblolly, fixed = list(R0 ~  : 
  step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step
```

After changing the starting values, it works fine.

```
model2 <- nlme(height ~ (R0) + 1,
               data = Loblolly,
               fixed = list(R0 ~ 1 + (age2)),
               random = list(Seed = pdDiag(list(R0 ~ 1))),
               start = list(fixed = c(R0 = 0, age2 = 30)), verbose=TRUE)
```

What are some ways of selecting starting values for `age2`? I thought about fitting a nonlinear least squares model using `nls2` but that requires specifying a set of starting values as well.

I was thinking maybe I could plot the data, `height ~ age2`, but since `age2` is binary...I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: If age2 is binary (and if a factor would be in the set {1,2}, (and therefore setting age2=30 makes no sense) , then might this be an integer programming problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `lm` like this:

```
fm.lm <- lm(height ~ age2, Loblollly) # modified Loblolly as per question
st <- coef(fm.lm)
names(st)[1] <- "R0"
nlme(height ~ (R0) + 1, data = Loblolly,
               fixed = list(R0 ~ 1 + (age2)),
               random = list(Seed = pdDiag(list(R0 ~ 1))),
               start = list(fixed = st))
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: height ~ (R0) + 1 
  Data: Loblolly 
  Log-likelihood: -305.1093
  Fixed: list(R0 ~ 1 + (age2)) 
R0.(Intercept)       R0.age21 
      12.96167       36.80548 

Random effects:
 Formula: R0 ~ 1 | Seed
        R0.(Intercept) Residual
StdDev:   0.0002791602 9.145988

Number of Observations: 84
Number of Groups: 14
```